# windows cmd not showing python virtualenvwrapper in front of the command

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, virtual-environment

I'm try to use "virtualenvwrapper-win" to build django project on my windows 10 pc. I think i setup it correctly, and it seems work fine. but I can't see what virtual environment am i using right now. it doesn't show in front of the command line. But on my laptop, i can see it correctly.

```
C:\Users\User>workon

Pass a name to activate one of the following virtualenvs:
==============================================================================

C:\Users\User>mkvirtualenv my_django
created virtual environment CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\User\Envs\my_django, clear=False, global=False) with seeder FromAppData pip=latest setuptools=latest wheel=latest app_data_dir=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv\seed-v1 via=copy

C:\Users\User>workon

Pass a name to activate one of the following virtualenvs:
==============================================================================
my_django

C:\Users\User>workon my_django
C:\Users\User>cdvirtualenv
C:\Users\User\Envs\my_django>
```

Above is the command line on my pc. I think i activate virtual environment correctly, but it didn't show what environment in the front. like below:

```
(my_django) C:\Users\User>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the new version 20.0.1 which doesn't show that, don't know whether its bug or not,the activate command does activate it, but it no visible. 
**Solution, uninstall and install last stable release**

```
pip install virtualenv==16.7.9
```

Comment: It really works, after i change my "virtualenv" to version 16.7.9. Thanks a lot of your help! it bothers me like whole night.

Comment: Not sure about others, but even after doing this, it still doesn't work for me.  Oddly, if I try activating the virtual environment in PowerShell, it does show the virtual environment prefix, though.

Comment: If virtual environment prefix is coming, what is the issue? Packages are are not installing?

Answer (score 1):

use the --prompt command line option.

eg.

```
virtualenv newenvironmentname --prompt "(newenvironmentname)"
```

or be even more clever...

```
virtualenv newenvironmentname --prompt "(here's the new environment)"
```